# Cookies change when I navigate to another page (Using jquery cookie)

Tags: cookies

For example, the user can change the font size, and it is remembered in the cookies. Say I am on the product page and change the font size there and add the cookie. Everything looks fine, but when I go to the front page, the font size is back to normal. Going back to the product page, the cookie is applied. How can I make the cookies work site-wide instead of per page? Or is there something wrong with what I am doing?

How I do it is, when the user checks a checkbox:

```
$.cookie('font', 'x2');
```

And on `$(document).ready()` I simply check the cookie and apply the css so:

```
if($.cookie('font') == 'x2') {
  $(body).css('font-size', '200%');
}
```

Or something like that. I don't think the problem is in my code though anyway, since it works, is this some kind of Drupal behaviour or...?

Comment: No it's not a Drupal behaviour, I use jQuery cookie in plenty of sites without any problems

Comment: Check if you have javascript errors when page loads

Comment: I don't have any javascript errors. I apply the font-size change and add the cookie and when I switch to any other page on the site, the cookie displays empty.

Comment: Try different machine/browser combinations to rule out local issues

Comment: Same thing everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really Drupal related, but it sounds to me like you are only setting the cookie for the current path.

Change:

```
$.cookie('font', 'x2');
```

to:

```
$.cookie('font', 'x2', { path: Drupal.settings.basePath });
```

Comment: Still not working... This is driving me nuts. Tried setting the path to the base path and anything I could think of, doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Is '/' the root of your drupal installation? Regardless, a more correct value for the cookie path (assuming you want the cookie available across your entire site) would make use of [Drupal's global javascript settings](http://drupal.org/node/304258) in `Drupal.settings`. I've update my answer accordingly.

Comment: This almost works. I will update the original post for further info.

Comment: I don't remember what didn't work for me, but I got it fixed. Your solution fixed this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout of a certain number of days on the cookie:

```
$.cookie('font', 'x2', { expires : 10 });
```